# ¿Porque libgdx no me permite crear un proyecto?

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

cuando presiono la opcion (generate) LIBgdx me sale este error:
your android sdk path doesnt contain an sdk.please install the android incluiding all plataforms and buils tools sdk. lo mas extraño es que descargue android estudio copie la direccion sdk desde hay y la pegue al proyecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> your android sdk path doesnt contain an sdk.please install the android
>   incluiding all plataforms and buils tools sdk

Me pasó lo mismo, lo que hice fue abrir el sdk manager desde android studio:
[image: SDK manager button]
E instalar lo necesario como los build tools y platforms:
[image: SDK tools tab]
Así LibGDX detectará el SDK, también fíjate que la diagonal sea la correcta "\" en vez de "/"

Comment: lastima que llegaste tan tarde pero te agradezco gracias